# problem loading in ${localEnv:TOKEN} into devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, containers

In my `devcontainer.json` for vscode, I am trying to load in a build variable. This variable is on my local machine's environment, my code looks like the following:

```
//build arguments
 "build": { 
    "args": { 
        "TOKEN": "${localEnv:TOKEN}"
    } 
}
```

It seems like it works when I put in a direct string, or something like `"${localEnv:HOME}"`, but it is not picking up this custom one. which is strange because I can do `'printenv TOKEN'` and it prints out correctly.

any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Add your `export BLA=1` to `.profile`, this was the only way VScode was able to pass through env variables to the `devcontainer`.

**.devcontainer**:

```json
{
    "name": "devcontainer",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "${localWorkspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
        "context": "${localWorkspaceFolder}",
    },
    "remoteEnv": {
        "FOO": "${localEnv:FOO}",
        "BAR": "${localEnv:BAR}",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that you have the VS Code `Terminal -> Integrated: Inherit Env` setting set to `true`. This is described on the [Advanced Container Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced) page:

[image: Adding env variable to dev container]

### Workarounds

If that doesn't fix your problem (it didn't for me), here are some of the workarounds that I have found:

1. Set the variables in your `~/.bashrc` file (or export them temporarily in the terminal) and start VS Code from a bash prompt (the executable is `code`).

```sh
$ export TOKEN=tokenvalue
$ code
```

2. Set the variables in your `~/.pam_environment` file (these are available [session wide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) and are inherited by applications started with the launcher). You will need to logout and login or reboot for these to apply.

```
TOKEN=tokenvalue
```

3. Set the environment variables in one of your VS Code settings files (user or workspace) using the `Terminal -> Integrated Env: Linux` setting:

```json
// Object with environment variables that will be added to the VS Code process to be used by the terminal on Linux. Set to `null` to delete the environment variable.
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "TOKEN": "tokenvalue"
},
```